# Row sum is equal 3 on a 5x5 grid

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have a 5x5 grid that every cell can contain one of two numbers $\ 0, 1 $ . What is the probability that at least in one row, the sum of numbers in that row will be $\ 3 $ .

I'm trying to follow the same logic as instructed in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980433/having-at-least-one-row-of-zeros-on-5-times5-board)

So the probability of row $\ i $ to have a sum of $\ 3 $ is $\ \frac{{5 \choose 3}}{2^5}  $ but this is not very helpful. so how do i construct it such that i'll be given the probability of all rows sums to be different than $\ 3 $ ?

Comment: You can work out the probability a row does not have a sum of $3$, then if the rows are independent the probability no row has a sum of $3$

Comment: I thought maybe the probability of any row not having sum of numbers equal 3 is $\ 1 - \frac{{5\choose 3} \cdot 5}{2^5} $ and so the probability of having at least one should be $\ 1-(1- \frac{{5\choose3}\cdot5}{2^5} )$ am I coorect?

Comment: One step at a time:    $1 - \frac{{5\choose 3} }{2^5}$ is the probability  a particular row does not have a sum of $3$.  But you have $5$ rows and you want this to be true for all $5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the cell values are independent, the probability that a given row has a sum of $3$ is 
$${\small{\binom{5}{3}}}\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)^5={\small{\frac{5}{16}}}$$
Hence the probability that a given row does not have a sum of $3$ is $$1-{\small{\frac{5}{16}}}={\small{\frac{11}{16}}}$$
Since the cells values are independent, so are the row sums, hence the probability that for all $5$ rows, the row sum is not equal to $3$ is 
$$
\left(
{\small{\frac{11}{16}}}
\right)^5
=
{\small{\frac{161051}{1048576}}}
$$
Hence the probability that at least one row has a sum of $3$ is $$1-{\small{\frac{161051}{1048576}}}={\small{\frac{887525}{1048576}}}$$